# Displaying author in single blogpost template

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have managed to create multiple authors pages programaticaly by fetching data from `yaml` file below

**data/author.yaml**

```
- id: jane_doe 
  name: Jane Doe 
  twitter: jane_doe
  bio: Chillwave lumbersexual chicharrones tote bag. Brunch ethical tbh mustache authentic raclette green juice
- id: john_doe
  name: John Doe 
  twitter: john_doe
  bio: Tacos edison bulb you probably haven't heard of them, before they sold out letterpress poutine pinterest
```

**the blogpost content**

```
---
title: "Heck Yeah Chillwave Heirloom"
author: ["jane_doe", "john_doe"]
---
```

everything goes right just like i expected but somehow i cannot dispaying the author it self in my single blogpost template

**src/templates/blog.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { kebabCase } from 'lodash';
import Layout from '../layouts/layout'
import moment from 'moment' // momentjs


// query content
export const blogQuery = graphql `
    query($id: String!) {
        singleBlog: markdownRemark(
            id: {eq: $id}
            ) {
            id
            html
            frontmatter {
                title
                author {
                    id
                    name
                    twitter
                    bio
                }
            }  
        }
    }
`
const BlogPost = ({data: {singleBlog}}) => {
   return(
       <Layout>
           <h1>{singleBlog.frontmatter.author.name}</h1>
           <div className="authors">
                            {singleBlog.frontmatter.author.map(a=>
                            <span className="tag" key={a.name}>{a.name}</span>
                            )}
                        </div>
       </Layout>
   )
}
export default BlogPost
```

i have no idea why `singleBlog.frontmatter.author.name` doesn't render anything while the query works in my graphql playground

```
{
  "data": {
    "markdownRemark": {
      "frontmatter": {
        "title": "Heck Yeah Chillwave Heirloom",
        "author": [
          {
            "id": "jane_doe",
            "name": "Jane Doe"
          },
          {
            "id": "john_doe",
            "name": "John Doe"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

any suggestion?

#### update

turns out that i have to map author as an array so i only have to change the way to render it

```
<div className="authors">
    {singleBlog.frontmatter.author.map(a=>
       <span className="tag" key={a.name}>{a.name}</span>
    )}
</div>
```

it render perfeclty now

Comment: The structure of your data in GraphQL playground and your code looks different. You aliased your `singleBlog` key to `markdownRemark` for your information.

Comment: since i was new in gatsby and react can you elaborate more detail, i add the same alias in my graphql and the result is the same  which is should be render the author.

Comment: @YudyAnanda check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59133565/6544460 and let me know if you need any help

Answer (score 1):

Access like this `singleBlog.markdownRemark.frontmatter.author[0].name`

Actually you were missing markdownRemark and also you can't directly put like author.name because author is an array so you need to do author[0].name or iterate author like `singleBlog.markdownRemark.frontmatter.author.map()`

- How to access object in javascript

  **singleBlog.markdownRemark.frontmatter.author**

  - markdownRemark is inside singleBlog ->so access like this `singleBlog.markdownRemark`
  - frontmatter is inside markdownRemark -> so access like this `singleBlog.markdownRemark.frontmatter`
  - author is inside frontmatter -> so access like this `singleBlog.markdownRemark.frontmatter.author`

After all author is array so iterate it.

Json

```
let singleBlog = {
    "markdownRemark": {
      "frontmatter": {
        "title": "Heck Yeah Chillwave Heirloom",
        "author": [
          {
            "id": "jane_doe",
            "name": "Jane Doe"
          },
          {
            "id": "john_doe",
            "name": "John Doe"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

react code

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let data = singleBlog.markdownRemark.frontmatter?singleBlog.markdownRemark.frontmatter.author:[];
    return (
      <div>
        {data.map(a=>
          <div key={a.name}>{a.name}</div>
          )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hi there, thanks for the answer, can you elaborate more detail about the code above?  what should i do with the json and how to integrate all this thing with my singleblog template?

Comment: never mind, i have figured it out by my self.  turns out that i have in to a map `{singleBlog.frontmatter.author.map(a=> <div key={a.name}>{a.name}</div>)}`. many thanks for lead me to the right path!

Comment: @YudyAnanda check this i updated with explanation how to access that.

Comment: @YudyAnanda if it's helpful for you please accept/vote for answer

Comment: since i have singleBlog as an alias for markdownRemark i simply dont have to call the markdownRemark but you are right about author as an array. thanks for the explanation. in this case i only change how to call the author as an array

Comment: @YudyAnanda but it's nested objects without that you can't go inside to access.

Comment: somehow it can, you can check my update above. thanks